# How to not trigger a build in Teamcity if only a specific file changed

Tags: git, build, triggers, teamcity

I am working with Teamcity as a build manager on a git repository;

currently, the trigger for creating a new build is if there are new changes.

the problem is, when building, the script i run creates a new commit of a specific file called version.txt (i increment the number there).

While finishing successfully, the commit is considered as a new change and on the next run , even if no other commits were made, the nightly build will be triggered.

I want to be able to create a rule that will not trigger a build if the only change pending is to the Version.txt file.

is there a way of doing that?

edit:
I've added a condition rule to team city: do not trigger a build if version.txt file has changed(see screenshot)
however, it seems this rule will cause the build not to be triggered if ,for instance, there are 2 pending changes which one of them is to the version.txt file

[image]

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Yep, you can do it.
Here are several options:

---

#### Update the `version.txt` before you execute the build.

Use a git hook to capture the commit and then you can update the build and commit it so you will have 2 commits which will your build will execute - the original one + the version update

---

#### Git hooks

Check in the commit hook for the files which are being committed.
If the only file is the version then skip the build

Here is an example of `post-merge` hook which runs after the user push code to the remote branch

```
#!/bin/sh

# Check to see if this is the first commit in the repository or not
if git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    # We compare our changes against the prevoius commit
    against=HEAD^
else
    # Initial commit: diff against an empty tree object
    against=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
fi

# Redirect output to screen.
exec 1>&2

# Check to see if we have updated the version.txt file
if [ $(git diff-tree -r --name-only $against | grep version.txt ) ];
then

    # Output colors
    red='\033[0;31m';
    green='\033[0;32m';
    yellow='\033[0;33m';
    default='\033[0;m';
    
    # personal touch :-)
    echo "${red}"
    echo "                                         "
    echo "                   |ZZzzz                "
    echo "                   |                     "
    echo "                   |                     "
    echo "      |ZZzzz      /^\            |ZZzzz  "
    echo "      |          |~~~|           |       "
    echo "      |        |-     -|        / \      "
    echo "     /^\       |[]+    |       |^^^|     "
    echo "  |^^^^^^^|    |    +[]|       |   |     "
    echo "  |    +[]|/\/\/\/\^/\/\/\/\/|^^^^^^^|   "
    echo "  |+[]+   |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|    +[]|   "
    echo "  |       |  []   /^\   []   |+[]+   |   "
    echo "  |   +[]+|  []  || ||  []   |   +[]+|   "
    echo "  |[]+    |      || ||       |[]+    |   "
    echo "  |_______|------------------|_______|   "
    echo "                                         "
    echo "                                         "
    echo "      ${green}You have just commited code ${red}   " 
    echo "         Your code ${yellow}is bad.!!!  ${red} Do not ever commit again       "
    echo "                                         "
    echo "${no_color}"
#fi;

exit 0;
```

---

#### Use smudge to update the version

The version increment will be done when adding code to the index (`git add`)
[image]

Comment: Thanks codeWizard for the detailed answer! however, at this point of time,  i'm wondering if there's a solution which doesn't require changing anything in the behavior of how the scripts interact with the git repository, but rather a Teamcity-related solution to the problem of trigger rules.

Comment: > ... require changing anything in the behavior of how the scripts interact with the git repository. | You can use server side hooks which has nothing to do with your local repository